# Why can't I start Blood on the Ice?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to buy Hjerim in skyrim and start the quest blood on the ice, I've already completed mourning never comes, I'm actually done with all the quests for the dark brotherhood, I've stolen the key from toca but the quest doesn't start, what do I do?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We already have quite a few posts about this quest, as a lot of people have trouble with it. Please look at the other ones, including the linked possible duplicate. If those don't answer your question, please add more details to your question to indicate that and how your situation is different. If your question is put on hold, don't worry, it can always be reopened once we have more details.

Comment: @DCShannon Whoops, I was mid-answer when you posted these... my bad!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UESP Page on starting the quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice#How_to_Start_the_Quest), there are a few prerequisites that the game requires before the quest will start.

`This quest is triggered by a counter that starts at the beginning of the game which will increase each time you visit the city of Windhelm or the immediate surrounding area. When it reaches four, the Blood on the Ice quest will be available, although two more conditions must be met.`

Those conditions are as follows:

1. You must enter Windhelm, either through the main gate, the docks gate, or by fast-traveling, between 7pm and 7am. The graveyard scene should then be triggered and the quest ready to go.
2. Tova Shatter-Shield and Arivanya need to be alive

All things considered, the quest should start. If the graveyard scene hasn't triggered for you yet, try leaving and coming back to Windhelm a few more times.